# Edit another users session in PHP

Tags: php, session

Is it possible in PHP to edit another users session other than the current user? If so how?

Comment: Sure, you can name your sessions manually, give PHP complete access to the temporary folder where sessions are stored, and destroy the security of your website!

Comment: There's no point on doing that, why would you wan't two users sharing the same session?, one session per user, that's all you need,

Comment: @Ben: Maybe he wants his admin session to be accessible by everyone that visits his website without them needing to know the password?

Comment: @animuson - Even worst, unless is a demo site. He just can override the login system as well.

Comment: I have a legitimate use-case for this: allowing an admin to modify a logged-in user's account without forcing them to log out.

Comment: ... what's all this about "two users sharing the same session" and "admin session to be accessible by everyone"? that has nothing to do with what OP asked, instead imagine PHP editing a specific users' session in real-time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to edit another users session in php through couple of ways:

1. 1st way is to you have to get SessionID of the user for which you want to edit session;

   ```
   session_id($SessionID);

   // and then enter code your logic to change session data here;
   ```
2. If you are storing your session data in database then it would be even easier to manipulate data directly in database which would update user session when application will request data again.

Remember you can play with user session up to any level the only thing required is SESSION_ID. 
If you got that you won the game;

Comment: Is it even possible to access somebody else's session using `session_id()`? I thought that function is just used to change the session ID of the current session for a particular user.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do that but the only thing is revert back session_id() to your current users actual session_id() else it would be a big mess.

So you need to code in following way:
- backup your current users session_id 

- initialize session with session_id of user for which you want to change data.

- logic to change data

- reset session_id to actual users session id from the backup you have taken.


I guess this should work :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on method which server use to store the session data.
I think there maybe a few ways to store like database, files on server, memcache server.
so you have to use a proper way.

anyway I've done web programming just for 5 months.
so I'm not sure what I said.