# Editing / updating a user's PHP session without talking to MySQL constantly

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm currently building a web application that uses a combination of OpenID and uname/pw authentication to authenticate users. Users are supplied a PHP session when they login successfully, and some information about their account (email address, usergroup, blah blah) is written to that session.

However, there may be a need for me or someone else as an administrator to update a users details (or to ban them immediately if they're very naughty). I'm hesitant to use a killsession tag like this (pseudocode):

```
session_start();
mysql_start(connection_stuff);
if (mysql_query("SELECT FROM users WHERE uid = '$_SESSION['uid']' AND KillSession = true")) { Kill session, force reauthentication };
```

However, doing it like this has two flaws:

1. We have to query the database every time someone loads a page to see if something changed
2. We gotta log the user out which just annoys him (or reload all of his session variables, which doesn't seem efficient)

Is there some way I can modify a user's session while they're still in it **without having to resort to forcing them to login again**? Some people seem to suggest [in this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892593/edit-another-users-session-in-php) using session_id to change to the user and then fiddle with their variables, but that seems like a shoehorn way of doing it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of storing that stuff along with the session, it should be kept (and cached) separately. That way you avoid data duplication and the issue you're running into right now.

If an admin needs to kill the session, just `DELETE` it from the table.

Comment: Wouldn't that still mean constantly talking to MySQL to check the session? That's what I wanna try to avoid.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry I assumed that you were storing sessions in MySQL. In that case yes you're going to have to check for a flag to kill the session. However, you could attempt to move sessions to another storage backend entirely ([redis](http://redis.io)) and kill it directly in there.

Comment: Redis looks awesome, and it's probably what I'll use if there isn't a way of doing it with sessions. Sessions just makes it hilariously easy to tie keyvalues to people, and it looks like I'd have to do a bit more running around if I did have to swap it over.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you express concerns about having to query the database on every page load, my guess is that it most likely does not affect performance noticeably. If the website is database driven in the first place, them it's just a matter of a single more query. I'd actually say that moving the entire session handling to the database (store session variables in a table)  can make your system better in terms on flexibility. It will be much easier to deploy your system on multiple servers and do proper load balancing if that is someting you think will become necessary at son point. That is how the bigger CMS systems handle their sessions. My advise is, in other words, to stick with the extra query and actually consider to move session state to the database.

Comment: It's less a case of extra queries and more a case of extra code. Right now, a fair amount of the site doesn't talk to MySQL **at all**, and only talks to it when an immediate change needs to happen (like account modifications) or during login - which keeps it really, really nippy. I'll consider sessionvar storage on MySQL as an option, though.

Comment: I do believe PHP allows you to register 'load' and 'save' functions which will be invoked to load and save session state. That might be worth looking into if you want to use mysql for storing session state and at the same time keep code to a minimum.