# PHP: destroy session when any link is clicked or on page reload

Tags: php

I gave Admin the privilege to disable a user account by toggling `user_status` from `Active` to `Inactive`. I have prevented the user account that was disabled from logging in by adding the block of code below to the top of my `dashboard.php`

dashboard.php

```
<?php
include_once("./database/constants.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
    $_SESSION[msg] = "You have to login first";
    header("location:".DOMAIN."/");
}

//For disabled account
if ($_SESSION['user_status'] == 'Inactive') {
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION[msg] = "Your account has been disabled. Please contact admin for assistance";
    header("location:".DOMAIN."/");
}

?>
```

My index.php is the login page and if `userid` is set, it redirects to `dashboard.php`

This is what is at the top of `index.php`

index.php

```
<?php
include_once("./database/constants.php");
if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
    header("location:".DOMAIN."/dashboard.php");
}
$message = '';
?>
```

I want to be able to destroy session once the user account that was disabled reloads the page `dashboard.php` or clicks on any link on `dashboard.php` (that is if he's logged in at the time when the account was disabled)

This is my `constants.php`, if it will provide additional help.

constants.php

```
<?php
session_start();

define("HOST","localhost");
define("USER","root");
define("PASS","");
define("DB","project_inv");

define("DOMAIN","http://localhost/inv_project/admin");

?>
```

Please, can i get some help? Do i need to use javascript?

Comment: So you want an admin to be able to destroy the session of another user?

Comment: Well, not directly. An admin just toggles the `user_status` from Active to `Inactive` and the code takes it up from there. I have been able to prevent the disabled user account from logging in. Now i just need to prevent him (if he is still logged in) from further activities on the site. Is there a way i can destroy his session when any link is clicked on or when any page is reload?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit another users session in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892593/edit-another-users-session-in-php)

Comment: @kmoser it gave an insight that i can tweak user session with `session_id`.