# I have a session variable in the navbar that displays correctly until that variable is updated in mysql

Tags: php, session-variables

I have the following in my navbar and is displaying the correct value, until the value is changed in mysql.  To display it correctly, I have to clear the session:

```
<a style="margin:10px;background-color:#EEA45A;border-radius:25px;padding:10px;" href="avail/index.php" class="true_home"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["availability"]); ?></a>
```

When the availability of the user is changed from Available to Unavailable, the session variable displays the value when the form is loaded.

Does anyone know if the session variable availability could be changed dynamically so the session does not have to end or the user does not have to log out?  Refreshing the page does not refresh this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make your code update the session at the same time it updates the database

Comment: Hard to suggest anything further without a [mre] of the issue

Comment: I will try updating the session at the same time it updates the database.  Thanks @ADyson

Comment: _"When the availability of the user is changed from Available to Unavailable"_ - changed by _whom_? Not by the user themselves, I assume, but by a page admin? Then you don't really have easy access to the _user's_ session at this point. Manipulating the data in a different user's session _can_ be done (https://stackoverflow.com/q/2892593/1427878), but it is a bit tricky, you'd have to get the logical sequence of ending & picking up different sessions exactly right. Plus, you'd have to store the user's current session ID somewhere to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe - The boss wants all users to have the ability to make each other available for leads in this sales app.  I created a trigger that inserts all changes in an audit table to track the history of users updating others' availability.  When each user is logged in, there is the link in the navbar that shows if he/she is available or not.  For each user, they may switch statuses many times per day, so I'll look into the link you supplied.  Thanks for that.

Comment: Given that information,  maybe its not really feasible to store the info in the Session, maybe you will need to query it from the DB every time you want to show it

Comment: @ADyson, I agree with you.  The issue is finally resolved, thanks to your statement about querying the DB.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone, this is what I did:

Per ADyson's suggestion, I removed the session for the availability field and used the following query for the currently-logged in user, since the username is a session variable:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'
```

Then, I just echoed the following:

```
<?php echo $row['availability']; ?>
```

The availability value for the logged in user now changes and quickly as it's updated.